# UWP ListView Quick Return Footer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I know Windows.Community.Toolkit has a `QuickReturn` `ScrollHeader`. But that's for the `Header` only because the collapsing direction for the footer is different from the header.

How can I make a quick return footer for the `ListView`? I am looking for some scrolling event that would help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `ScrollViewer` to wrap the `ListView` to get the scroll event of the ScrollViewer.

**xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView> 
                 ...
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private double scrollLocation = 0;

private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (viewer.VerticalOffset > scrollLocation + 3)
    {
        // scroll down, show the footer
    }
    else if (viewer.VerticalOffset < scrollLocation - 3)
    {
        // scroll up, hide the footer
    }
    scrollLocation = viewer.VerticalOffset;
}
```

By listening to the ScrollViewer's `ViewChanged` event, you can determine the scroll direction, and the reason is `+3`, `-3`, mainly to eliminate the unconscious scrolling of the mouse or touch, reduce false positives.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! What if I don't want to hide the footer immediately? I mean like hide the footer as you scroll. What is the method that can move the footer downward a little?

Comment: Two ways, the first, you can set Margin's Bottom to a negative value. Second, use RenderTransform -> TranslateTransform.Y to adjust the position of the control on the Y axis.